# Regex do not change anything

Tags: java, regex, string

Please have a look at the below code

```
public class PuctuationRemover {

    public PuctuationRemover()
    {
        String str = ":The red; third.fox is hungry!!! but, is he angry? doesn't! (yeah!). Call 911! system. can't access it! what the , hell . is this. people of my country, really? 123465 can^be,found.... OK . you got it? ";
        String str2 = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z'\\s]+", str);

        System.out.println(str2);
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new PuctuationRemover();
    }

}
```

The expected output is

```
The red thirdfox is hungry but is he angry doesn't yeah Call system can't access it what the hell is this people of my country really canbefound OK you got it
```

The output I get is

```
:The red; third.fox is hungry!!! but, is he angry? doesn't! (yeah!). Call 911! system. can't access it! what the , hell . is this. people of my country, ..............
```

The original working regex is [here](http://regex101.com/r/lU9kO3).

What has gone wrong here?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to use `String str2 = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z'\\s]+", "");` instead?

Comment: @Robin That link is borked, try enclosing it with `<>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to remove the punctuation, supply an empty string as the second argument instead of the original string itself.  The second argument to [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is not the original string, but what to replace the match with.  Change

```
String str2 = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z'\\s]+", str);
```

with

```
String str2 = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z'\\s]+", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  String `str2 = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z'\\s]+", "")`;

You are doing `String str2 = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z'\\s]+", str);` .You are replacing the whole original String.

Please see this  [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for more on String replaceAll.

Here in `public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` second argument, i.e `replacement` is the string to be substituted for each match.

**Note:** Its better to catch `PatternSyntaxException` .

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing your old string with your old string, which means you keep the same string even after replacing it. What you need to do is replace all of the characters specified in the regex with a no-character `""`.

EDIT: Darn, you people are fast typers! =P